# Why is this creating duplicates instead of the unique CoreData entries?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to preload some data into CoreData when the view loads for the first time and there are no entries yet and its created the correct number of entires, but then it's making them all the same values (duplicates of the same item). The idea is to create a CoreData entity with preloaded Achievements which the user can then earn throughout the app, which will just update the 'completed' attribute of that entry. Problem is, it's creating the correct number of entries, but it's creating them all the same. Here is what I currently have:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct AchievementView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Achievements.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)])
      private var achievements: FetchedResults<Achievements>


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color("Background")
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        let completedCount = achievements.filter(\.completed).count
                        let totalCount = achievements.count
                        let pctComp: Double = (Double(completedCount) / Double(totalCount)) * 100
                        
                        Image(systemName: "star.circle").padding(.leading, 5)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        Text("Achievements".uppercased())
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(completedCount) OF \(totalCount) (\(pctComp, specifier: "%.f")%)")
                            .font(.system(size:16))
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    }
                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(achievements) { achievement in
                                HStack {
                                    VStack {
                                        if achievement.completed == false {
                                            Text(achievement.image ?? "")
                                                .padding()
                                                .grayscale(0.99)
                                                .overlay (
                                                    Circle()
                                                        .stroke(Color(.systemGray6), lineWidth: 2)
                                                ).padding()
                                        } else {
                                            Text(achievement.image ?? "")
                                                .padding()
                                                .overlay (
                                                    Circle()
                                                        .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)
                                                ).padding()
                                        }
                                    }
                                    VStack{
                                        if achievement.completed == false {
                                            HStack {
                                                Text(achievement.name ?? "")
                                                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray2))
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                            HStack {
                                                Text(achievement.desc ?? "")
                                                    .fontWeight(.light)
                                                    .font(.system(size:10))
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray2))
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            HStack {
                                                Text(achievement.name ?? "")
                                                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                            HStack {
                                                Text(achievement.desc ?? "")
                                                    .fontWeight(.light)
                                                    .font(.system(size:10))
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                }   .background(Color("WeekShowBack"))
                                    .cornerRadius(15)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.padding()
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .onAppear(perform: loadAchievements)
    }
    
    private func loadAchievements() {
        
        print("Number of Times Called")
        let achievementNames = ["First Entry", "Movie Starter"]
        let achievemnetDesc = ["Enter your first movie or show", "Track 10 Movies"]
        let achievementComp = [false, false]
        let achievementImage = ["",""]
        
        if achievements.count == 0 {
            
            for index in 0..<achievementNames.count {
                let newAchievement = Achievements(context: self.viewContext)
                newAchievement.name = achievementNames[index]
                newAchievement.desc = achievemnetDesc[index]
                newAchievement.completed = achievementComp[index]
                newAchievement.image = achievementImage[index]
                
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                    print("Achievement Loaded!!!!!!")
                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How many times is this func called? Put a `print` at the start and check it's only called once.

Comment: Just once when I go to that view. So the .onAppear for the view is calling the function once. Its creating the correct number of entries (2), but it is making them both the same ("Movie Starter" "10" "Track 10 Movies")

Comment: I have to ask, how do you check that they are the same?

Comment: I don't understand your question @Joakim Danielson. I don't have any code to check for duplicates but the end goal here is to create a list of CoreData entries for that Entity (Achievements) that is preloaded when the view is loaded for the first time. Since the arrays have unique info at each index, it should be creating 2 unique entries in CoreData. But instead it is creating 2 of the exact same...

Comment: I mean how do you know there are two duplicates persisted in Core Data? You are probably right in what you say but I just want to verify there isn’t a mistake when loading/checking the stored values

Comment: I added the foreach in the view and the .onappear code above so you can sort of see more. It's created 2 entries with duplicate entries because when it's displayed on the view itself, it has the same name, same description, etc. It should have the different names, different descriptions, etc. per the arrays.

Comment: And you use a @FetchRequest I assume?

Comment: Yes: ```@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Achievements.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)])
      private var achievements: FetchedResults<Achievements>```

Comment: What is `id` here, I don't see that attribute anywhere else?

Comment: if You want to call this loadAchievements method only once the parent view loads 
add onAppear(perform: loadAchievements) to the top most view not for the forEach i thing that will work

Comment: @ Joakim - id is the UUID of each entry. I changed it to name and same results. | @Ahemd - Tried adding it to the NavigationView and same results (NavigationView sits right under the body view itself). | *** It's loading the entries into CoreData, but not how I have it in the array. Its just duplicating one of the entries to match the number in the array ***

Comment: try to move the do block inside the for loop in the loadAchievements function try to save inside the for loop

Comment: @AhmedMohiy - Same results.....this is really frustrating and confusing to me

Comment: is it possible to share the whole swiftUI file ?

Comment: @AhmedMohiy - Done, updated original posting with the entire file. The Achievements entity has the following attributes: name(string), desc(string), completed (bool), image (string), id (UUID)

Comment: Do you get duplicates when you first install the app, or do they appear when you run the app more than once after installing it?

Comment: @TomHarrington - It creates the correct amount of entries (there are 2 items in the array). It just creates two of the first or two of the 2nd in the array, making duplicates. It only does this on the first install. After that, nothing changes or adds on to the list.

Comment: I would advise you to learn how to examine what has actually been persisted in the underlying SQLite db so you can troubleshoot cases like this properly. There are 3rd party apps you can use and/or you can turn on core data debug logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out...thank goodness! This was driving me insane but I'm not sure why this matters as I thought CoreData automatically assigns one. Anyways, I added this line to the do statement in the function:

```
newAchievement.id = UUID()
```

Now it's creating the correct achievements in CoreData and now I can get on to actually coding each achievement. Thank you everyone for the assistance!

Comment: yeah i created the app and i found this error in the console

ForEach<FetchedResults<Achievements>, ...... the ID nil occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!